# Trying to understand Dapper Multi Mapping

Tags: c#, dapper

I have been going through [Dapper's Multi Mapping documentation](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) but remain confused.

This is the example from Dapper documentation

```
class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public User Owner { get; set; }
}

class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

var sql = 
@"select * from #Posts p 
left join #Users u on u.Id = p.OwnerId 
Order by p.Id";

var data = connection.Query<Post, User, Post>(sql, (post, user) => { post.Owner = user; return post;});
var post = data.First();
```

What confuses me is where the variable `post` and `user` came from? I see in this line ...

`connection.Query<Post, User, Post>`

that `Post` and `User` are the models and I understand that ..

`(post, user) => { post.Owner = user; return post;}`

is a function that defines the mapping, but where do `post` and `user` get instantiated?

Comment: They don't "come from" anywhere, it's a [lambda expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx), go have a read about them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a Lambda function. Don't know the technical explanation, but basically connection.Query returns multiple records, each containing a post and user as per the query. With (post, user) => you're declaring that post will represent the Post and user will represent the User from each record.